# Web application functional requirements dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am developing a machine learning project which analyzes requirement specification and categorizes the functional requirements into categories like database, web socket, backend technology, etc. I'm planning to use topic modeling and LDA to categorize into these categorizes but I wasn't able to find a proper dataset for this. If someone can help me out, I would highly appreciate this.

**for an example**

*data should be stored in a secured and scalable store ==> database
a large number of user requests should be handled ==> backend*

**or**

> database

*data should be stored in a secured and scalable store*

*search should be fast*

> front end

*easier technology solution to maintain the user interface*

Answer (score 0):

pdf of a large IT system's functional requirements document.

https://www.fns.usda.gov/sites/default/files/apd/FReD-v2.0-Final.pdf

Comment: Maybe our definition of functional requirement is different.

Comment: would be nice for downvoter to explain ...

Comment: I want a dataset which lists functional requirements of categorizes like database, front end, etc. So requirements should be labelled with their category or list the requirements under the categorizes from where I can create the dataset I want.

PS: I didn't downvote your answer, and thanks a lot for trying to help me. +1